# char* vs const char* in C

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings, string-literals, const-correctness

```
char* str ="Hello";
```

In the above code the literal "Hello" is stored ... in the DATA segment and it is read-only.
So isn't it better to always declare it:

```
const char* str = "Hello";
```

to avoid improper code such as:

```
*(str+1) = 't';
```

Comment: You'll get at least warning in newer versions of compilers for the first syntax.

Comment: The data segment is not read-only, so on a system with read-only memory segments, it may not be stored there.

Comment: BTW, no-one *really* writes `*(str+1)`, except people who do not realize that `str[1]` is a *pointer operation* not an array one.

Comment: @nabroyan: Neither [Clang](https://godbolt.org/z/n8c5nh) nor GCC for x86_64  give such a warning, even with `-Wall`. In fact, none of the compilers on Godbolt give such a warning except for AVR gcc. Are you think of C++?

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Yes, my comment relates to C++. Either I was not attentive to tags or C++ was removed from tags afterwards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "Hello" is stored ... in the DATA segment

"DATA" or `.data` would refer to the segment where initialized read/write variables with static storage duration go. String literals are not stored there, but more likely in something called `.rodata`, or possibly in `.text` along with the code. 
See [String literals: Where do they go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589949/string-literals-where-do-they-go)

> So isn't it better to always declare it: `const char* str = "Hello";`

Yes, you should always `const` qualify pointers to string literals. This is universally considered best practice in C (and mandatory in C++).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is better to declare pointers to string literals as `const char *`. The name "literal" very strongly suggests that this is something that is supposed to be immutable.  Unfortunately, C treats string literals as arrays of `char`, not `const char`, and unlike numeric literals storage for the string literal must be allocated from somewhere.  It is not guaranteed that this storage will be taken from a read-only segment like `.rodata` - I've worked with implementations in the past where string literals were writable.

The behavior on attempting to modify the contents of a string literal is *undefined* - the language places no requirement on the compiler or the runtime environment to handle the situation in any particular way.  You *may* get a runtime error, or the string *may* be left unchanged, or the string *may* be modified, any something entirely different could happen.

So by declaring the pointer as `const char *`, you're at least making it harder to *accidentally* modify a literal through that pointer.  Just remember that `const` *doesn't* mean "put this thing in read-only memory" - it only means "issue a diagnostic if someone tries to modify this thing".